# How to `quote` an arbitrary structure at runtime into a `TokenStream` to create it?

Tags: rust, macros

Let's say I have an enum like the following:

```rust
pub enum Categories {
  A,
  B
}
```

I would like to get a function that converts a value `x: Categories` into a `TokenStream` that represents the same value. This function would have to work like so:

```rust
let converted: TokenStream = convert(Categories::A);
println!("{}", converted.to_string());
//=> Categories::A
```

Think of this as going from a runtime value of an object to its `TokenStream` representation. Perhaps there is some crate/macro decorator that I could use to decorate this object:

```rust
#[derives(TokenStreamConverter)]
pub enum Categories {
  A,
  B
}
```

That could then create a converter function for it automatically?

Comment: Not the direct answer to the question as-is, but probably you're looking for something like https://lib.rs/crates/uneval? (Disclaimer - I'm the author of this crate; there may be something similar from someone else)

Comment: You should probably write a Serde serializer that emits `TokenStream`. Maybe there is already one in the wild.